# Why is my zip file not showing any contents?

Tags: c#, typescript, c#-ziparchive

I've created a zip file method in my web api which returns a zip file to the front end (Angular / typescript) that should download a zip file in the browser. The issue I have is the file shows it has data by the number of kbs it has but on trying to extract the files it says it's empty. From a bit of research this is most likely down to the file being corrupt, but I want to know where I can find this is going wrong. Here's my code:

WebApi:

I won't show the controller as it basically just takes the inputs and passes them to the method. The DownloadFileResults passed in basically have a byte[] in the File property.

```
    public FileContentResult CreateZipFile(IEnumerable<DownloadFileResult> files)
    {
        using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(file.FileName);
                    using (var entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                    {
                        entryStream.Write(file.File, 0, file.File.Length);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip");
        }
    }
```

This *appears* to work in that it generates a result with data. Here's my front end code:

```
let fileData = this._filePaths;
this._fileStorageProxy.downloadFile(Object.entries(fileData).map(([key, val]) => val), this._pId).subscribe(result => {
            let data = result.data.fileContents;
            const blob = new Blob([data], {
                type: 'application/zip'
            });
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url);
        });
```

The front end code then displays me a zip file being downloaded, which as I say appears to have data due to it's size, but I can't extract it.

***Update***

I tried writing the compressedFileStream to a file on my local and I can see that it creates a zip file and I can extract the files within it. This leads me to believe it's something wrong with the front end, or at least with what the front end code is receiving.

***2nd Update***

Ok, turns out this is specific to how we do things here. The request goes through platform, but for downloads it can only handle a BinaryTransferObject and I needed to hit a different end point. So with a tweak to no longer returning a FileContentResult and hitting the right end point and making the url simply an ahref it's now working.

Comment: looks like you return the zip stream before it's getting flushed (dispose did not get invoked) Try and flush it before the return

Comment: @WalterVehoeven - you mean the compressedFileStream?

Comment: I tried altering it so that rather than returning inside the using of the compressedFileStream, a 'FileContentResult fileResult' object is created outside of that and the result is is then set to that and returned after the using statement. However, it got the same result.